# How can I create method for passing values from Activity to other components

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I need the `chapterId` and `lessonId` value in `Tablayout` fragments .

one of the solution to send data from activity to fragment is sending value with public method in activity and create a new instance in fragment and give the value in fragments .

I have This activity where i get bundle in that .

```
 public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private String chapterId;
        private String lessonId;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

            getBundle();

        }

        private void getBundle() {
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

            if (bundle != null) {
                chapterId = bundle.getString("CHAPTERID");
                lessonId = bundle.getString("LESSONID");
            }
        }

      ========  Method for sending data to other Activities and Fragments=====
        public String  getId(){

        }

    }
```

Now my question is how can i write this method . Thanks

Comment: do you want passing data from activity to fragments?

Comment: i know using intent , my mean is creating method for passing value between Activty and fragment .

Answer (score 0):

**for activity:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,yourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("bundle",bundle);
startActivity(intent)
```

*in activity :*

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 if (extras != null) {
            chapterId = bundle.getString("CHAPTERID");

        }
```

**for fragment**

```
Fragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
myFragment.setArguments( bundle );
```

*in fragment*

```
Bundle extras = getArguments();

if (extras != null) {
            chapterId = bundle.getString("CHAPTERID");

        }
```

Comment: I use this sulution befor , but i getting null pointer exception in that

Comment: can you please share your code how you used it.

Comment: I use this topic , but i get null pointerexception  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12739968/5620129

Comment: this is valid . I think you have to check it from your side . you can paste your snippet of sending bundle so we can get idea what is the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can do this type

Declare Two Methods

```
public String getChapterId()
{
    return chapterId;
}
```

and second methods

```
 public String getLessionId()
{
    return lessonId;
}
```

Comment: This is not good sulution for this work

Comment: Yes i know but you cana...